error after installing pyttsx3 module in python
import pyttsx3 

engine =  pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voices',voices[0].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    speak("Hi, I am Veraa")

I was trying to use pyttsx3 module to make Jarvis speak but my system  said that pyttsx3 is not installed and it throwed a MoudleNotFoundError even after install the module

Maybe this answers your question? Python 3.6 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'

Does this answer your question? Python 3.6 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'
